# expected unqualified-id expected before {

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm trying to write an open system call in inLine assembly. I've read that removing the ; is my issue. But I am trying to call the open system call and set fd, my file descriptor, equal to that, not declare a function.

```
#include "syscall.hh"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{

    char *buffer;
    int i = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int woc = 100;
    int loopCnt; 
    int inBufferSize = 0;
    int fd;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: cp file1 file2");
        return 1;
    }
      /////***this is the line where i believe my issue is***///
    fd = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 3;
    }
    //end if

    if (argc > 0)
    {
        inBufferSize = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("inBufferSize = '%i' \n", inBufferSize);
    }
    //end if 


    buffer = new char[inBufferSize];
    for (i = 0; i < inBufferSize; i++)
    {
        buffer[i] = 'a';
    }
    //end for

    fd = 0;

    loopCnt = (woc / inBufferSize); 
    for (n = 0; n <= loopCnt; n++)
    {
        my_write(fd, buffer, inBufferSize);
    }
    //end for


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your implementation of the syscall?

Comment: Also (as you probably already know, but just in case) ``;`` declares a comment in assembly...so if you commented directives that are supposed to execute something, it surely will help to remove the ``;``

Comment: Hey I found it, the problem was an extra } in syscall.cc, I just kept looking in main.

Comment: You provided the `assembly` tag, but I don't see any assembly language.  Did I miss it?

Comment: You say you're using inline assembly, but there is zero assembly code in your question.

Comment: My apologies my inline assembly was in my syscall.cc inside the my_write function